# pdf in binary format

Tags: python, pdf, text, bin

I am trying to understand how binary files work.
I opened pdf file (book page) in binary format with python interpreter and then printed part of context on the screen:

> b'%PDF-1.4\r\n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n19 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Linearized
> 1\r\n/L 60759\r\n/H [ 1325 184 ]\r\n/O 21\r\n/E 58759\r\n/N 1\r\n/T
> 60252\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n ...

and the main contents of the file looks like this:

> \r\nstream\r\nh\xde\x1c\xc3\x03\x90\x10\x08\x00\x00\xc0\xcb\xae\xcf\xc6\x7f\xb6\xed\xfal\xdb\xb6\x8d\xc9\xb6m\xdb\xb6m\xdb\xb6];\xed\xcc\x06\x04\xfc\x15\xc8\xc0\x061\xa8\xc1\x0cn\x08C\x1a\xca\xd0\x861\xac\xe1\x0co\x04\xff1\xa2\x91\x8cl\x14\xa3\x1a\xcd\xe8\xc60\xa6\xb1\x8cm\x1c\xe3\x1a\xcf\xf8&\xf0_\xff3\xa1\x89Ll\x12\x93\x9a
> ...

If I understand it correctly, interpreter already converted all binaries it could into text - here we received text "nendobj", "Linearized", etc. I checked other symbol combinations, f.e. \xde and they are not valid binaries. What do they represent then?

Answer (score 2):

The question "how binary files work" is too broad, since e.g. JPEG files, MP3 files, executable programs, ... are "binary files". Heck, even UTF-8 text files are binary files, if you consider "text files" to just be a human-readable subset of bytes.

> If I understand it correctly, interpreter already converted all binaries it could into text

You're seeing the Python `repr()` of a `bytes` object; that's not the original content. All of the `\x..` sequences are Python escape sequences for bytes that are otherwise unrepresentable as ASCII text.

IOW, the representation is NOT the same thing that's in the file you opened and read.

To see another sort of representation of the same binary file, you might want to try and open it in a hex editor. Here's the start of the output of some arbitrary PDF I had laying around, run through the `xxd` hex dumper:

```
00000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e33 0a25 c7ec 8fa2 0a38  %PDF-1.3.%.....8
00000010: 2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c2f 4c65 6e67 7468   0 obj.<</Length
00000020: 2039 2030 2052 2f46 696c 7465 7220 2f46   9 0 R/Filter /F
00000030: 6c61 7465 4465 636f 6465 3e3e 0a73 7472  lateDecode>>.str
00000040: 6561 6d0a 789c cd5b 4fa8 1e57 1547 d445  eam.x..[O..W.G.E
00000050: 3f1e 2fbc d7b4 f4d5 68a7 a142 429b dbfb  ?./.....h..BB...
00000060: 7fee d59d 6083 56a4 090f 41f9 68d1 bc24  ....`.V...A.h..$
00000070: 6d62 be9a 2fd6 18e8 52c5 9d20 e8b2 942a  mb../...R.. ...*
```

On the left is the offset to the file in hexadecimal, followed by hexadecimal bytes in the file, and on the right, the character representations of whatever can be represented as text (and what can't, is a `.`). You can see the same `%PDF-...` header appear there, but none of the `\xe2`s and so on, since they're just a representation.

As for the specification of the PDF file format, you can find it here (as a PDF...) on Adobe's site. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: I would suggest pointing to the newer ISO norms instead of the older pdf references. Adobe provides a copy of ISO 32000-1 for free which you can find by googl'ing "PDF32000".

Comment: @mkl Good catch, corrected. I had just copied the link from Wikipedia's External Links section. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How binary files work

**Almost all** computer and network streams or **files are binary** i.e bits of 0 or 1 (only a rare few may be qubits). They may travel or be **stored in serial or parallel** fashion. Originally it was easy to use "**by** eigh**t*e*s**" to describe 8 bits (often in parallel) and show them as two hexadecimal characters (each is a nibble). Modern computers tend to stream 64 bits in parallel, but we stick with easier established older conventions.

**A valid PDF must start** with a "Header" as **0010010101010000010001000100011000101101** that's its 40 bit binary signature and in Adobes 2008 standard definition that's described as part of an 8 bit comment, which then also indicates the version number.

Some PDF's were tolerated by Adobe, and other PDF Readers, if that Digital Signature including terminal line feed was somewhere in the first 1K block (8192 bits or 1024 bytes) Those files (where the signature is not directly at the start) should now be rewritten as considered invalid.

When we convert the binary to human terms, we consider bytes as optical characters thus the 5 bytes of those 40 bits when translated looks like `%PDF-` and your view shows that as b' for translated binary notation followed by %PDF-1.4 then \r (represents **R**eturn the printer carriage) and \n (represents move Paper UP to form a **N**ewline, again human perception says we move down the page!)

In other notation those \r\n are shown as CR LF (usually a dos/windows construct) they are also sometimes shown in **\** he**x***idecimal* as a 16 bit "word" 0D0A and in python speak could be shown as \x0d\x0a but in reality they are binary 0000110100001010 which is not human friendly.

After time you get to recognise and read the different types of human shorthand since reading binary would be a **bit** too hard.

So a PDF can be written in 7bit ASCII Plain Text using say NotePad However those characters are moved as 64 bits stored as 8 bit bytes which in turn are really binary, but we describe those files as not binary because they only have a few 8bit characters !! Confused ?

**Later Edit**
If we look at your PDF header we see this structure the 19th **obj**ect by number is placed in 1st position) which you spotted as Linearized [This information is then web served as sequential content "chunks" of PDF binary.](https://www.pdftron.com/blog/pdf-format/what-is-pdf-linearization/)
Thus we can say with much certainty the file is classed "binary" (but all printout files are actu**all**y binary :-)

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
19 0 obj
<<
/Linearized 1
/L 60759
/H [ 1325 184 ]
/O 21
/E 58759
/N 1
/T 60252
>>
endobj
```

The short header gives little away about the file it is the next few objects that give us most information about page size or editor history. However I will hazard a guess and it is a guess that the low level of numbers suggest few objects on the page thus it is likely it is a page with a picture of text thus not textual.

Comment: I don't quite get it - why if my pdf is a bookpage with text, no images, open as binary file, python interpreter can't convert it to text format? It converted some metadata at the beginning of the file but not the contents?