# What kind of file is ".qopslol"?

Tags: file, file-type, file-type-associations

Hi I need to manage some files from an old repository (very old repository) some of these files have the extension "`qopslol`" which I have never seen in my life.

They seem to be an 'add/modify/extend to pdf files as the file names are in the form of "`xxx.pdf.qopslol`" or "`yyy.pdf.qopslol`".

I had already tried to open like a "pdf", but unsuccessfully and it is not a zipper or a tar file . Online binary analysis tools give me as result the generic mimetype "application/octet-tstream" .

In my ignorance it would look like some custom file for a specific scanner, but I can't figure out which one it is.

Can anyone tell me what type of files they are and what software to view them with ?

Comment: The extension by itself doesn't mean anything. First thing to try is see if they open as PDF's. Since it's pretty easy, second thing to do is try with a .zip extension. Third thing to do is inspect with a binary editor and see if the file editor gives anything away. Is there anything in the repo that give you a clue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I had already tried the "pdf" test ^^, but unsuccessfully it is not a zipper or tar file and online binary analysis tools give me as result the generic mimetype "application/octet-tstream" (I should have specified it in the application)

Comment: A binary editor wil show you the header. Most files have a header that tells whatever is opening it that it's a valid file. For example, if it _was_ PDF (I understand it isn't), you'd see this in the binary editor https://stackoverflow.com/a/68662487/1690193

Comment: Confirmed is not a PDF

Comment: _in this case the % is missing so adobe will not open it, even though it has valid ending_ are you saying that it is almost a valid PDF it's just missing one character at the start? Then clearly this _is_ a PDF that someone has fiddled with.